# How to set default value in react-hook-form in react-native using custom register method

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I was testing out react hook form and referring to the documentation [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#ReactNative). Kindly note that this question is specifically referring to the **Custom Register** method of a manual register.

Passing `defaultValues` into `useForm()` does not work as `defaultValues` doesn't auto populate with the manually registered input, as stated in the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#useForm).

In that case, is there any way to set default value using this method?

```html
export default function App() {
  const { register, setValue, errors } = useForm()

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>First name</Text>
      <TextInput
        ref={register({ name: 'firstName'}, { required: true })}
        onChangeText={text => setValue('firstName', text, true)}
      />
      {errors.firstName && <Text>This is required.</Text>}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for react native use Controller from react hook form

example

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
export default function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => Alert.alert(
    "Form Data",
    JSON.stringify(data),
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>First name</Text>
      <Controller
        as={TextInput}
        control={control}
        name="firstName"
        onChange={args => args[0].nativeEvent.text}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        defaultValue=""
      />
      {errors.firstName && <Text>This is required.</Text>}

      <Text>Last name</Text>
      <Controller
        as={TextInput}
        control={control}
        name="lastName"
        onChange={args => args[0].nativeEvent.text}
        defaultValue=""
      />


      <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

for more information check documentation  [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#ReactNative)

Comment: thank you for the answer. however, my question was specifically for the custom register method, which does not use Controller

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass register to ref???

It should be used like this:

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName'); 
// include type check against field path with the name you have supplied.
        
<input 
  onChange={onChange} // assign onChange event 
  onBlur={onBlur} // assign onBlur event
  name={name} // assign name prop
  ref={ref} // assign ref prop
/>
```

```
// same as above
<input {...register('firstName')} />
```